# Add SSH-Key for nginx user (for github)

Tags: github, ssh, nginx

I'm running into a bit of issues with nginx and SSH keys.

I need to add a ssh key for the nginx user to access private github repositories and then run the "git ..." commands to pull or clone the repo onto my Ubuntu box.

With the nginx user just being a worker task is it possible to generate a key for this user?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11):

You can run commands as another user without having to provide their password using `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -u nginx ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@address.com"
```